# Improve performance of EventstoreDB

Tags: java, performance, kubernetes, eventstoredb

I am using ESDB v 20.10.2.0. This is deployed in a docker container in Kubernetes cluster; data and logs are stored in the same installation directory. We use Java client to read the stream from the esdb server, pfb the code snippet.

```
ReadStreamOptions readStreamOptions = ReadStreamOptions.get().fromStart().notResolveLinkTos();
DomainEventDeserializer deSerializer = new DomainEventDeserializer();
try {
  List<ResolvedEvent> resolvedEvents =
      client.readStream(addPrefix(aggregateId), readStreamOptions).get().getEvents();

   return resolvedEvents
      .stream()
      .map(
          resolvedEvent -> {
            byte[] eventData = resolvedEvent.getOriginalEvent().getEventData();
            return deSerializer.deserialize(null, eventData);
          })
      .filter(data -> data != null)
      .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
```

The reading events from esdb is taking 3x the time compared to reading something from an sql db.
I would like to know what could be the optimal configuration for this and how to improve the read performance.

> .\EventStore.ClusterNode.exe --db .\db --log .\logs --insecure
> --run-projections All --enable-atom-pub-over-http --enable-histograms --reader-threads-count 8 --worker-threads 10 --log-http-requests

this is the command used to run esdb in my local system, same options are enabled in kubernetes cluster also.

Comment: Is the SQL Server also hosted in the same Kubernetes cluster?

Comment: The cluster also hosts PostgreSQL, but my application does not use it, it only uses ESDB.

Comment: My question was - you say "reading events from esdb is taking 3x the time compared to reading something from an sql db", so are you comparing two products which are hosted in the same Kubernetes cluster, have the same resource limits, and use the same storage class?

Answer (score 3):

I can't explain why you are having those results based upon what you shared but a few notes on the matter:

- Kubernetes is hardly recommended for databases, even less for performance testing.
- It seems you are using a dated version of the Java gRPC client, certainly a 0.x version.
- A key limitation of the current Java gRPC client is it doesn't support streaming of large events. The returned list is constructed fully before returning anything to the user. Depending on how you set up your test, it can impact your results. There is open PR to address it: https://github.com/EventStore/EventStoreDB-Client-Java/pull/79. This is a limitation other official clients (C#, Rust, NodeJS, Go, ...etc) don't have. There is no asynchronous stream type in Java. We want to maintain a Java 8 compatibility while keeping the dependency graph as small as possible.

Comment: I am using a gRpc of 1.31.1 version and db-client-java version 1.0.0 , if Kubernetes is not recommended then what do you recommend for it? Also currently it is running as a single node, will making it a cluster improve the read performance?

Comment: Clustering won't improve read performance, it's for high availability. Unless you can tolerate reading events, which might have not been replicated yet, using the node preference.